# Where does Safari Web Inspector store images?

Tags: safari, web-inspector

I am currently running OS X El Capitan, Public Beta 3 and trying to download images within the Safari Web Inspector.

What I did:

1. Opened a website in Safari.
2. Opened the Web Inspector.
3. Selected one of images from the Images folder.
4. Right-clicked and selected "Download Image".

Unfortunately, nothing happened.

Should the images be downloaded to the Download folder? Am I missing something, or is it a bug in the latest Safari Beta?

Comment: I always just do a copy and the paste into preview.

Comment: Or drag the image into a Finder window

Answer (score 3):

This indeed looks to be a bug.

You can watch all file access on your system with the `opensnoop` command. This requires root access - run it, then try hitting the download button - you'll see no access from Safari.

Time to hit Feedback Assistant and tell them what's going on!

The earlier comment is a good workaround - once the image is displayed, just hit CMD-C to copy it for pasting elsewhere.